# Why are users who do not exist allowed to login using this bit of script?

Tags: php, authentication, pdo, passwords, prepared-statement

I have some PDO:

```
if (empty($this->user->username) || empty($this->user->password))
    throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);
include('dbconnect.php');       // Normally I'd store the db connect script outside of webroot
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_password);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT userFName FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND roleID = 1');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $this->user->username);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $this->user->password);
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $userFName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
try {
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Invalid username or password: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$this->user->firstName = $userFName;
```

If the POSTed username and/or password are wrong, a login still occurs. I think something is wrong with the PDO; did I miss something critical when trying to check $this->user->password against the record in the DB?

(btw, I am using encryption)

Comment: Why not leave out `AND roleID = 1` ?

Comment: where are the lines where you are checking and redirecting to the login page?

Comment: Above this section. I fixed it, though :)

Comment: mmHmm. I forgot rowCount()

Comment: Tip (if you don't already know that): `$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` (or `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`)will return associative array containing all the data collected from the database and put it into `$res`. I think that's easier way to access query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt->execute();
```

will not throw an exception if there are no results. You need to check if the query result returned a row for the user.

edit:

```
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    //user found
} else {
    //user not found
}
```